# data isn't saving into db using eloquent relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to save data into db using Eloquent ORM one-to-one but it is not saving and not showing any error to  fix it (m unable to find any solution about it because it is not showing any error),

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'owner_id' => 'required',
        'phone_name' => 'required|unique:phones'
    ]);

    $phone = new Phone;
    $phone->owner_id = $request->owner_id;
    $phone->phone_name = $request->phone_name;
    $phone->save();

    return redirect()->route('phone.index')->with('flash_messages_success', 'Phone has been added successfully');
}


protected $fillable = [
    'pphone_name', 'owner_id'
];

public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Owner');
}


   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('phone.store') }}">
  @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Phone Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone_name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Phone Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Owner</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
        <option selected="">Under Owner</option>
        @foreach($owners as $owner)
        <option value="{{ $owner->id }}">{{ $owner->owner_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: You have a typo in ```$fillable```. ```'pphone_name'``` should probably be ```'phone_name'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in select name you named category_id so the view should be:

```
<select class="form-control" name="owner_id">
```